# How to determine if a sparse matrix is structurally symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory

Say you have a sparse matrix in CSC or CSR format (or whatever format is suitable for this to work) and all you know are it's dimensions: $n$, $m$ and $nz$, and the data in the structure. You are told nothing about the structure or layout.

A description of the CSR format: http://netlib.org/utk/papers/templates/node91.html#SECTION00931100000000000000

How would you determine (from the $row\_ptr$ and $col\_ind$ arrays) if a sparse matrix is structurally symmetric?
Is there a simple and efficient method?

An (obvious) property of a structurally symmetric matrix is that every row $x$ in the matrix has the same number of elements as each corresponding column $x$.

Is that one of the defining properties of a sparse symmetric matrix?

If we had a square sparse matrix $A$ where every row had the same number of elements as its corresponding column, i.e.:

- $numel(A(i,:)) = numel(A(:,j))$ where $i = j $ $\ \forall i,j \in n$

Would it be then true that $A$ is structurally symmetric?

Experimentally this does seem to be the case. Unfortunately my Linear Algebra and Graph Theory is not up to any sort of proof.

**EDIT:**
Ok. The above does not hold true for a permutation matrix where every row/column just has a single entry.
However, can anyone suggest a matrix where $nz>n$ or there is a at least one row/column with 2 or more elements, which is not symmetric?

Cheers,

-- El Bee

Comment: By the way, if you know only the dimensions of the matrix ($n$ and $m$) and the number of nonzeros, there's no way how you could claim anything about the structural symmetry. You need to know also the actual matrix (except the numerical values of the entries ofc).

Comment: @PavelJiranek - Apologies if that was confusing, I was asking how to determine the structure just by looking at the data (column pointers, row indexes) in the matrix structure.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way how to check that the graph of a sparse matrix (assuming the CSR storage) is symmetric, is to find the corresponding $(j,i)$ entry for each $(i,j)$ entry. The complexity (in terms of the number of comparisons of indices) is bounded from above by $\mathrm{nz}\times\mathrm{r}_\max$, where $r_\max$ is the maximum number of nonzeros per row. So assuming that there is about the same number of nonzeros per row, it gives about $\mathrm{nz}^2/n$. Of course, this can be reduced if the column indices are already sorted by using the binary search.

Another option, which requires an additional $n+\mathrm{nz}$ storage, is to first build the transpose of the graph and compare the two graphs. Transposing the graph requires has about $n+\mathrm{nz}$ complexity. To compare the original and transpose, it is better to have the column indices in both sorted or at least in the original graph to use the binary search while iterating over the columns in the transpose. This bounds the number of comparisons by something like $\mathrm{nz}\times\log(r_\max)$.

Comment: Thanks for that - Thanks especially for the counter example :)
Needing to scan the row $i$ for every element becomes expensive, making it an $O(nz \times n)$ operation. I was hoping to find something $O(nz + n)$ or less.

Comment: Yes, I also realized that checking only the "transposed" entries of the lower triangular does not make the whole story work :)

Comment: You might want to believe also the statistical methods which test the values of $y^TAx$ and $x^TAy$ for random $x$ and $y$ (with $A$ replaced by, say, $A$ with nonzero entries replaced by 1's). However, this method won't be cheaper than direct checking, is not guaranteed to provide the right answer, and rounding errors can affect the evaluation of the dot products. It is used to check the symmetry of $A$ when $Ax$ is provided by some black-box routine.

Comment: One way to check for symmetry is to transpose the matrix out of place, and then compare the two ptrs[] arrays and the two indices[] arrays. If they are identical the matrix is structurally symmetric. A big memory overhead, but it is $O(nz + n)$ compared to your $O(nz \times n)$ - I'm not which method would actually be faster though :)

Comment: Just a note: In $O(nz+n)$, $nz$ is not the number of nonzeros in the matrix but the length of the "maximal sized" column (CSC) or row (CSR). If it would be the total number of nonzeros, then the comparison algorithm would be quite useless :) Also: if you would have a "flag" container with an $O(1)$ access for an $(i,j)$ entry, then the comparison could have just $O(nz)$ complexity. The direct solution (in the answer) has the advantage that no additional memory allocation is needed.

Comment: For every non-zero (or at least $\frac{nz}{2}$) element $a_{ij}$ you need to check if an element exists in its transposed position by (if not on diagonal) scanning the $i$ column for an element with row index $j$. Your two outer for loops iterate over all $nz$ elements - for each column, for each element within that column.

Comment: Yes, it is actually $O(\mathrm{nz}\cdot\mathrm{nz}_{\max})$, where $\mathrm{nz}$ is the *total* number of nonzeros and $\mathrm{nz}_{\max}$ is the maximal number of nonzeros per row/column (CSR/CSC) as stated in the answer. You have to iterate over all nonzeros (unless you can keep track of the already visited ones which you can't without an additional array) and each check compares no more than $\mathrm{nz}_{\max}$ indices.